# I want to add discount coupon code in my web application with a implementing the shopping cart feature in java using authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

How can I configure the coupon codes in authorize.net?
Is there any place in accounts or I have to do it manually declare the coupon codes in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must apply any discounts prior to sending the transaction for processing.

Comment: so i have to process the coupon code with my code and then send the final amount ?

Comment: yes i got the way from authorize.net forums ..i have to code it myself or use a third party plugin.. please share any refrence for this it will really helpful thanks..